# Azure WebApp Deployment task not recognizing variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When running the following task in a pipeline

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: Web App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    WebAppName: $[dependencies.preDeploy.outputs['webAppName']]
    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/PackageTmp'
    WebAppUri: WebAppUrl
    UseWebDeploy: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-useChecksum'
    RenameFilesFlag: true
    enableXmlVariableSubstitution: true
```

it complains about the variable I am assigning to the WebAppName

```
##[error]Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name '$[dependencies.preDeploy.outputs['webAppName']]'. Error: {"error":{"code":"InvalidFilterInQueryString","message":"Invalid $filter 'resourceType EQ 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' AND name EQ '$[dependencies.preDeploy.outputs['webAppName']]'' specified in the query string."}} (CODE: 400)
```

Why is the variable not being replaced with its actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable needs to be addressed by its reference name, which is usually the step name the variable came from.

> If you want to make a variable available to future jobs, you must mark it as an output variable using isOutput=true. Then you can map it into future jobs using $[] syntax **and including the step name which set the variable**.

More reading about [Multi-job Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable)

See `myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['`**`setvarStep`**`.myOutputVar'] ]`
in the below example.

```
jobs:

# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
    name: setvarStep
  - script: echo $(setvarStep.myOutputVar)
    name: echovar

# Map the variable into job B
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]  # map in the variable
                                                                          # remember, expressions require single quotes
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
    name: echovar
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed naming the step and then assigning the variable to a local variable.